# Connection refused when sending flask app to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my flask app on amazon elastic beanstalk. Whenever I deploy i received the following error.

`2020/06/08 17:03:46 [error] 4311#0: *217 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.81.233, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.89.203"`

I have attached the stdout and error log below.

```
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Jun  8 16:50:15 ip-172-31-89-203 web: * Serving Flask app "application" (lazy loading)
Jun  8 16:50:15 ip-172-31-89-203 web: * Environment: production
Jun  8 16:50:15 ip-172-31-89-203 web: WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Jun  8 16:50:15 ip-172-31-89-203 web: Use a production WSGI server instead.
Jun  8 16:50:15 ip-172-31-89-203 web: * Debug mode: on
Jun  8 16:50:15 ip-172-31-89-203 web: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

this is the startup command for my app

```
    application.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False, host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

The app runs fine locally but does not when deployed to EB. What is the issue and how can i fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey Josh, Did you find the solution

Comment: Hi @Namshad_muhammed I'm sorry but I can't recall the outcome off the top of my head. I can only assume that I did not end up finding a solution because I would have updated this post at the time if I had. Sorry I cannot be of more help

Comment: its ok. If I find any I will definitely post the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the host and port from your `application.py`:

```
application.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Automatically, Flask app is served inside your Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance on 127.0.0.1:5000 and then is exposed externally through NGINX.

Comment: ```connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.89.233, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.91.253```
this error is still present after making that change. Do i need to expose the port somehow?

Comment: After making the changes, did you run `eb deploy`? If yes and if your project is on Git, you have to commit your local changes before running `eb deploy`.

Comment: no change. the error same error still exists. it fails to deploy with those loggin information